# Training neural network by making batch_size increase to avoid shocking

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

```
... build the graph ...
train_step = 
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = data.next_batch(batch_size)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

In a typical tensorflow neural network training, we usually make the `learning_rate` decay, but rarely make the `batch_size` increase. I think making the `batch_size` increase could also make the neural network converge and avoid shocking. This is my suggestion to train a neural network. Do you think it could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

**If your descent is noisy:**

Increasing the `batch_size` will stabilise the fluctuations, as the gradient will be averaged over a higher number of samples.

The effect of halfing the `learning_rate` is similar to that of doubling the `batch_size`, but not the same (think vector-wise how this is different). halfing the `learning_rate` is better from a mathematical point of view, but doubling the `batch_size`, might(!) be computationally more convenient.

**In case of low noise:**

Reducing the `learning_rate` is the only viable option. If your gradient direction is not noisy, then increasing the `batch_size` is not going to change the situation much. A smaller `learning_rate` could however be useful, as a big step could make the gradient direction not representative, and you could exit the "valley".